# Prepared Statements Paypal IPN Listener SQLi ( PHP )

Tags: php, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Using prepared statements *( New language to me )* to process data passed to from paypal to be stored within my database.

So for this example I am attempting to add **transaction_id** *($txn_id)* and **payment_status** *($payment_status)* to my database.

The code below shows the defining of the variables and my attempted prepared statement.

*This is where I believe the error to be.*

**Note:** I have tested with an IPN similator and it is receiving the message and responding to the server, however the problem is, it's **NOT** storing the values in the database.

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process payment and mark item as paid.

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $custom = $_POST['custom'];







        $query = "INSERT INTO payment (transaction_id, payment_status) VALUES(?, ?)";
        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

        //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
        $statement->bind_param('is', $txn_id, $payment_status);

        if($statement->execute()){
         print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
        }else{
         die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
        }
        $statement->close();
```

Here is the rest of the code within the IPN receiver.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php'
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}


// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];








    $query = "INSERT INTO payment (transaction_id, payment_status) VALUES(?, ?)";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
    $statement->bind_param('is', $txn_id, $payment_status);

    if($statement->execute()){
     print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
    }else{
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();

    /*if($payment_status == "completed")
    {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `is_member`= 1 WHERE `username` == $username')
    }
    else
    {
       mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `is_member`= 0 WHERE `username` == $username')
    }*/


    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why you use the same code to generate more and more questions? The site idea is totally different. Just asking a questions coming from real practice

Comment: @Pavel why do you constantly comment on peoples posts with answers you've already posted on an alternate question, which has little to no relation?

Comment: Continue with thinking another question with same code :). I will stop a visit the questions posted from your account, because I think you are a cheater

Comment: I'm more than happy for you to stop posting on my questions.http://www.hive.co.uk/Product/443697?gclid=CM3It5Kj0cgCFYQfwwodMiIPyA Please view the link and make yourself a purchase :)